# How to prevent user from leaving app or locking user in the same screen?

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart

I'm creating a children's app and I want to lock the screen (no going back or leaving the app or going to home menu same thing like Samsung's children space) when you're in the children space (which is just a screen with a many playlists of videos or music), you'll only be able to exist the space if you authenticate using fingerprint or enter the correct pattern or even face id.

Answer (score 1):

Samsung as a manufacturer has special privileges and access to System APIs that the normal app developer will not. I know you can consume the `Back button` at the `Activity` level but you can't consume the `Home` button or `Overview` button.

Both keycodes

`KEYCODE_APP_SWITCH`(Overview) and `KEYCODE_HOME` are not delivered to your `Activity` but are instead handled by the `OS` which is `Samsung` flavor of `Android` and they can then intercept and handle those codes as they see fit.

I believe in much older versions of `Android` like `pre-4.0` you could do something like this easily, but its an obvious security risk. So only system apps can use this kind of stuff in modern `Android`.

Depending on the phone you can disable these buttons via `Settings`, meaning you could prompt the parent to disable them on first startup.

All in all if you do figure out a kinda solution it wont be pretty.

```
 //Here is the way you can catch the back button though.
 @Override
 public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {\
     //Catch the back key and return
     if(KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK == keyCode){
         return false;
     }
     return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
 }
```

EDIT: You also have the `Flutter`/`Dart` tags, and you even have more restrictions with using that api instead of the native one.

Comment: Thank you for your clear answer, so it seems there is no solution to pevent a kid from clicking the home button and leaving the app at any moment